# Insert value to a table from another table using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I want to create a register form and automatically insert a value from another table I'm currently using this code:

```
´$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO ram (fecha, sintomas, reaccion, seguimiento, comentarios, severidad, idpac, idfarmaco, idtrat) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['fecha'], "date"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['sintomas'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['reaccion'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['seguimiento'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['comentarios'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['severidad'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($row_Recordset2['idpaciente'], "integer"));
```

idpaciente is the column I'm tryong to automatically insert but this doesn't seem to work.
I generated the code using Dreamweaver Insert record wizard.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Using Dreamweaver's default SQL code is not always the best plan. It's an artifact from the 1990s that's never really been updated.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" isn't enough detail, though. Does it produce any output? Yield any errors? Is there anything that can narrow down the nature of the problem?

Comment: Whenever I create the registration the column appears as null and I get the following message:
Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in C:\xampp\htdocs\reg4.php on line 53
Query was empty

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for 9 values and you're only giving 7 ( GetSQLValueString), just delete the last 2 values that you aren't giving and your code should be like this:

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO ram (fecha, sintomas, reaccion, seguimiento, comentarios, severidad, idpac) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['fecha'], "date"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['sintomas'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['reaccion'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['seguimiento'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['comentarios'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['severidad'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($row_Recordset2['idpaciente'], "integer"));
```